# How to solve "Could not find the task 'gcc build active file." error in VSCode?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gcc, visual-studio-code

I've just setup **VSCode** to work from home with my remote **SSH** that runs **Gentoo x64**. Everything works fine apart from the **GCC** debugger which we usually use. It throws me the error in the title.

Here's my `launch.json`:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "gcc - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "gcc build active file",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
    }
]
}
```

and my `tasks.json`:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "/usr/bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build"
    }
]
}
```

And yes, I do compile with the `-g` flag. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add gdb configuration:

In the debug menu, left side, click the debug icon, in the top you have a drop down menu where you have you default config `"gcc build active file"`, you will need to click that and select `"add configuration"`, select `(gdb) Launch`, this will add to the `launch.json` something along the lines of:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Of course mine is windows so yours will be different.

You might have to configure the name of the executable, working folder, gdb location, etc.

Then in the same dropdown menu select `(gdb) Launch`