# Use VS Code Integrated Console for C++ Debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

[image]

I want to debug my C++ Application in the Integrated Console provided by VS Code, but I am not able to find any options for it. I can't even provide input to the Program. The output of the program is being redirected to the "Debug Console" of VS Code.

I am using the Official Extension for C/C++ provided by Microsoft.

[image]

This is my launch.json

[image]

And this is tasks.json

[image]

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/61192643/6865932

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend is getting the extension called Code Runner from the Visual Studio Code's extension library. Then, what I would do is go File -> Preferences -> Settings and at the top type run code. Then scroll down to where it says code runner: run in terminal and check that. After that, I would restart Visual Studio Code and then try running the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check your gcc/g++/gdb version and try to use an more updated version.

In my case, the version goes with `mingw-w64 with git bash (GCC 6.2.0)` is NOT supported by vscode Integrated Terminal for debugging. However, using an more up-to-date version - `GCC (12.2.0)` will show your debugging in your integrated Terminal (at least in my case).

Suggested alternative GCC installation: [WinLibs - For Standalone GCC](https://winlibs.com/)